# Construction of Square

Tags: geometry

I am having a problem constructing this square for some reason as i am not sure where to put the point X:

Let ABCD be a square and X a point such that A and X are on opposite sides of CD. The
lines AX and BX intersect CD in Y and Z respectively.

Is CD perhaps a diagonal?
If so how can BX intersect CD in Z.
If it is not a diagonal: Where must X be i.e. what are the opposite sides of X?
and if they are not diagonals again how can BX intersect CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if a polygon is named like ABCD then it means that its vertices are A, B, C and D, and you meet each vertex in that order by walking along the edges of the polygon (usually anticlockwise). So CD is not a diagonal; AC and BD are diagonals.

The picture I have in my head from your description is something like this:
[image]